# Dry principle and using keyword

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-2.0, dry

how to implement DRY principle in the following code?
Can we eleminate multiple "using" keywords with one

```
   public void CreateFile()
    {
        using (FileStream f1 = new FileStream(@"C:\\Test",FileMode.Create))
        {

        }

    }
    public void FontClass()
    {
        using (Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not repeating yourself. `using` is there to ensure whatever resources are used by it get disposed at the end. I suppose you could encapsulate it, but how are you going to get less than one line of code?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can manually `Dispose` each object. But do you really want to?

Comment: You're not repeating yourself, you're doing two different things, albeit using the same mechanism; but the complexity of "genericising" this method of operation, if possible, may well outweigh just doing it ad hoc.

Comment: Your question sounds like `Can I use FileStream` for `Font` since both are `f1(identifier)` ? I don't see any repeated code here. Both are different operations. You're using `new` keyword in both places does it mean you're repeating it? can you eliminate it?